# Clear Kendo Validator error messages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, mvvm, kendo-ui, kendo-validator

I have a form with multiple controls, the validation condition is set in the model  using regular expressions, when the condition does't met the error messages shown beside the control. I have another button to clear the validation error messages. How to clear those messages

```
                     $("#student-details").kendoValidator();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Taken verbatim from the [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/validator#methods-hideMessages):

```
// attach a validator to the container and get a reference
var validator = $("#myform").kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator");

//hide the validation messages when hide button is clicked
$("#hide").click(function() {
    validator.hideMessages();
});
```

Comment: Tried this way got this error "JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'hideMessages"

Comment: this was introduced with Q1 2013, so if you use an older version, try this workaround: $(document.body).find("span.k-tooltip-validation").hide()